# .Net Core 2 WebApi to SQL Server using Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, dapper, intranet, sql-server-2017

I am working on a project where I am using .net core 2.

I have a Client app, which calls an Web API, with the API doing communication with the database (SQL Server 2017). As this is an internal (Intranet) app only, we are using AD (Active Directory) as our method of authentication an security of the app.

When working locally the App and DB uses the users details (i.e. name and login details) correctly and are passed through the app and used by the API to talk to the database. The database call then using suser_name to automatically record the users name in a table. We need to know the individual users actions, not use a SQL Server Login which used by the app as a whole.

When the application is moved to the test environment, a web server (IIS8.5) which holds the client and the API in different virtual directories and the database which is on a different server. Both servers are in the same domain (NL-TEST).
When updating the connection string from:
Server=LT017180;Database=Payments; Integrated Security=SSPI;
to Server=testserver;Database=Payments; Integrated Security=SSPI;
it will not connect to the database.

I have confirmed that the user (NL-TEST\Joe_Bloggs for example) is setup in the security section of the database server and has access to the database and is in the NL-TEST domain as a user (I have set it to db_owner, just to try to get it to work).

I have confirmed that the API does have the users credentials. How do I get the credentials to the database so that it logs in as the user and accesses the database?

Example of my code:
**Client**
Startup

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<Entities.APIs>(Configuration.GetSection("APIURLs"));
        services.AddPolicies(Configuration.GetSection("Policies").Get<Policies>());
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**API**

```
public IDbConnection Connection => new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    [HttpGet("payment/employee/{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<PaymentDTO> GetByEmployeeId(Int64 id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("EmployeeNo", id, DbType.Int64);

            dbConnection.Open();
            var payments = dbConnection.Query<PaymentDTO>("api.GetPaymentsForEmployeeNo", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            dbConnection.Close();
            return payments;
        }
    }
```

**Ajax call to API**

```
        var onAjaxSuccess = function (data) {

       // do something
    };

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: href,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        error: function (result) {
            // record an error
        },
        success: onAjaxSuccess,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        processData: false
    });
```

**Controller to API call:**

```
private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true});

        private static async Task<PaymentDTO> GetPaymentsDetails(Int64 paymentId)
    {
        var url = new Uri(ApiUrls.PaymentsAPI + "/payments/payment/" + paymentId);

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var payments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentDTO>>(jsonString);
            var payment = payments[0];

            return payment;
        }
        return new PaymentDTO();
    }
```

Am I missing a setting or wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to .NET Core, all you'd have to do is disable Anonymous Authentication, enable Windows Authentication, and enable Impersonation (either via the web.config of the project or if deploying to IIS you can also do it in the Authentication settings of the site.)

.NET Core scrapped Impersonation so this is no longer possible. Without being able to use Impersonation, when deployed to IIS, the application (and connections to the database) are executing as the AppPool user of that site (not the actual user browsing the site, even when Windows Authentication is enabled).

They do offer a somewhat legacy solution for how to impersonate the Windows Authenticated user but it isn't really recommended, especially for heavy units of work. Read on the **Impersonation** section at the bottom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Alternative solutions to this problem are:

- Develop your own login screen to get a reference to the users credentials and use those to make your database connections (obviously this should be implemented in a secure way)
- Implement OAuth authentication